Planning of Solana Trading Bot
I was thinking of developing a automated trading bot for interacting with the Solana blockchain. And have two questions I'm a bit curious of:

What is the rust library eco-system like with Solana compared to python, as my initial thought is too develop the project in cython unless rust is a legitimate viable option
Does Solana have an official WSS or do they just have the RPC https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/

Thanks all

To answer your first question: I do not recommend working with Python on Solana, since the libraries are often outdated/ unavailable. I would recommend working with either Rust, js/ts, or even golang. There are lots of libraries for these languages that can speed up development time.

Depending on your Trading bots functionality I must say using up to date features will save you a lot of trouble. If you think practical, practical will happen ,but if you think too far out the box then you might be punching holes into cardboard.
